# Cognito Google Federated Identity, Invalid OpenId Connect Identity Token

Tags: openid, openid-connect, amazon-cognito, google-openid

I am working on an app that allows users to login using their google account, and then uses that login to get a Cognito federated identity.

I am unable to get the correct token needed to authenticate with Cognito. I keep getting the error `com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Not a valid OpenId Connect identity token.`

Here is my code:

```html
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CognitoSyncClientManager.init(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

                String token = null;

                try {
                    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), signInAccount.getAccount(), "oauth2:openid");
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d("login exception", e.toString());
                }
                Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
                logins.put("accounts.google.com", token);
                CognitoSyncClientManager.addLogins("accounts.google.com", token);
                Log.d("login", "Created User token " + token);
                Log.d("login", "Cached UserID: "+CognitoSyncClientManager.credentialsProvider.getCachedIdentityId());
                Log.d("login", "UserID: " + CognitoSyncClientManager.credentialsProvider.getIdentityId());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Created user: "+CognitoSyncClientManager.credentialsProvider.getCachedIdentityId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
        t.start();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GoogleAuthUtil's getToken seems to return an Access Token.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context, android.accounts.Account, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)

You need pass Google's OpenId Connect Id Token to Cognito and not Access Token.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

Comment: Thank you so much! I would give you 100 up votes if I could!

Comment: Thank you, using id_token instead of access_token fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Javascript passport-google-auth module, it returns access_token, refresh_token, and params.

for getting cognito_identity you need to use params.id_token received from Google

```
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(googleDeveloperDetails, getUserDetails));

    app.get("/auth/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ['email'] }));

    var authGoogle = passport.authenticate("google", {
        failureRedirect: "/auth/google"
    });

    app.get("auth/google/callback", authGoogle, controller.successRedirect);

    getUserDetails = function(accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, done) {
          if(profile.provider == "google") {
           profile.token = params.id_token   // params.id_token to be used to get cognito credentials
          } else {
                profile.token = accessToken;
          }
          done(null, profile);
    }

    googleDeveloperDetails = {
        clientID: "google cleint ID",
        clientSecret: "google client secret",
        callbackURL: "https://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback",
        profileFields: ["emails", "profile"]
    }
```

Comment: This does not appear to work any longer with passport. There's no `params` object passed thru to the callback function. Is there any other way to get the OpenID Token specifically? Having trouble getting that.

Comment: @AndrewHummel: I had the same issue and found the answer here: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/issues/108#issuecomment-174185520. TLDR; you can add a parameter and get at that `params` object that's being mentioned